# How to get svg code of (Gauge)google visualization api from browser's dom in IE 7 or IE 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, pdf-generation, google-visualization

I am using google visualization api to dynamically generate chart([gauge](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge)). I need to collect generated svg from browser's dom and send it to server to generate a png image from it(using [apache batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)). I am able to get SVG code from browser's dom in firefox,chrome,safari and IE 9 using javascript's 'innerHTML'. But when i try the same in IE 7 and IE 8, I get empty iframes in the innerHTML text. Here is the javascript code, I am using to get svg part from html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['gauge']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() 
{
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Memory', 80],
        ['CPU', 55],
        ['Network', 68]
      ]);

      // Create and draw the visualization.
      new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data);
      alert(document.getElementById('visualization').innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gauge should fall back to VML in older versions of IE. Even if you got the VML code I doubt Batik can parse it.

Comment: Thanks!!. I was unware of this. I have to generate a pdf report and show the gauge in the report. I am using flying saucer to covert html to pdf. But my in IE, I was unable to get SVG from dom. I was planning to get svg and then convert it to png using batik.And then use png in pdf conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about getting the svg converted to png which gets rendered on client side.Then this can be achieved on server side using jsdom and node.js.JSDOM is a DOM implementation of browser on server so that you can execute client side javascript on the server itself.

Here is an example of how to convert svg to png using jsdom,node.js and imagemagick

[click here](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2011/12/converting-dynamic-svg-to-png-with.html)

Hope it solves your problem!